# Access database issue

Tags: vb.net

I am running some windows application that has access table attached.
Now after instaling the application on some computer, I'm trying to 
find that access table (to change some data manually or change the location of the database) and I cant find it anywhere.

the application works fine with the database so it has to be somewhere on the PC.
do you have any idea where can I find it?

Comment: Did you forget to include the database file in the installer?

Comment: Somewhere in AppData probably.

Comment: No I did include it. and the application work fine (it cannot work without the DB). it's wired but I cant find it no where

Comment: You can use Resource Monitor in Windows to see disk activity related to a program - database file activity should show up.

Comment: If this is a ClickOnce installation look at trying ApplicationDeployment.DataDirectory for the path and if not ClickOnce try AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory. e.g. use the following in an if statement IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Somedatabase.accdb")) or use the first method. See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx